# Query not obtaining data from two tables

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to obtain the number of rows present in two tables. The two tables involved are:

- `flagged_posts`: Which has `3` rows.
- `flagged_comments`: Which has `1` row.

Here is what I have:

```
$all_flagged_posts = mysqli_query ($connect, "SELECT * FROM flagged_comments c LEFT JOIN flagged_posts p ON c.id AND p.id");
        $num_of_total_flagged_posts = mysqli_num_rows ($all_flagged_posts);
        echo $num_of_total_flagged_posts;
```

But the echo produces the result `3`, when it should be `4`?

Answer (score 0):

Since you want the count of the rows without any relational checking - you can use `union`

```
select sum(cnt) as total_count
from
(
   select count(*) as cnt from flagged_comments
   union all
   select count(*) from flagged_posts
) tmp
```

Comment: Arn't you missing a `cnt` there in the second query

Comment: No, only the first query defines the column names

Comment: @juergend - Hi, thanks for your answer. I have changed my query to exactly what you have above. But when I run `$num_of_total_flagged_posts = mysqli_num_rows ($all_flagged_posts);` , it echo's the value of `1`?

Comment: Of course the query returns one record - the result of the counting. Don't check the record count. Check the value the query returns

Comment: @juergend - Not sure whether Im misunderstanding you, or vice versa, but I am trying to get the number of rows present in both tables. There are four rows present in both tables in total, so I am looking for an echo which returns 4.

Comment: You can either select all records, throw all that data away and just count the rows the result retured. But that is not that great. Better is to let the DB count the records and return just one result - the number of records it counted. So execute the query and extract the value from it.

Comment: For instance look at this example for how to select from DB in PHP http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysqlquery.php

Comment: out of curiosity, is there a big difference between using `union` here and `inner join`?  if OP wants the common rows in both tables?

Comment: Yes, if OP wants common rows a JOIN would be the right way to do it. That is what it is designed for - relating tables. I don't see an easy way getting common rows with UNION.